# Grub with Windows 10 and Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, windows

I had Windows 10 and I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on it. Here is my drive situation:

Drive 1: SSD, Windows

Drive 2: Two partitions. Windows uses the first one. Ubuntu is installed into second one.

After installing Ubuntu, it would always boot into Linux. I ran Boot Repair from Ubuntu with the "recommended repair" option. Now I just boot into the grub command line. I can boot into Linux or Windows by pointing BIOS to a hard drive (hitting F11 during boot).

Here is the log that Boot Repair generated: http://paste.ubuntu.com/26163895/

Any suggestions on how to fix this? I just want Grub to appear without having to press the BIOS's F11 during boot.

Comment: did boot repair install grub to the MBR? Legacy boot can not read a GPT disk.

Comment: @ravery, BIOS boot on gpt works if you have a bios_grub partition. Bit of a unusual configuration as you have the older MBR partitioning which normally is for BIOS boot on sdb, but are booting in UEFI mode thru the ESP - efi system partition on sda. But that may not be issue. What brand/model system. Some only want to boot Windows. You can then only boot with your f11 or do a work around. Several work arounds: http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789 I would plan to eventually convert sdb to gpt, but not required.

Comment: Does it boot to windows if you select windows from the grub menu ? On my laptop I have to select which OS to boot from the efi "bios" , grub will not work for me (although I have not tried to debug recently)

Comment: @oldfred -- I know, but I doubt bootrepair put a bios grub. the most likely fix is to reinstall grub, but we have to fix what boot repair did first

Comment: Only very old versions of Boot-Repair would add a "Windows" boot entry using a copy of grub in /EFI/Microsoft. But there are two "Windows Boot  Manager" entries which may confuse things. Not sure if that was even done by Boot-Repair. But one is Ubuntu and one is Windows. Better to have standard "ubuntu" entry if UEFI allows that, or a work around if UEFI not standard like with most HP & Sony.

Comment: I think Boot Repair asked to install grub to MBR @ravery and I accepted something along those lines. This is a quite new computer: http://www.sanalmarketim.com/Urun/EXPER-XCELLERATOR-XP870-Gaming-Core-i7-6700-Z170-16GB-240GB-SSD--2TB-GTX1080-Wi-Fi-Win-10-700W-Full-Tower/615 I can boot into Windows when I select it from the grub menu. I tried Boot Repair multiple times, so it may have made things worse each time. So, should I let Windows fix the boot/mbr/whatever, and then try to install grub again?

Comment: The computer is probably trying to boot Legacy mode, thus grub cant find its config file and drops to rescue mode. Use windows to fix the boot. this will give a windows only boot. From the `boot select menu` (F11) launch ubuntu and reinstall grub. this should give you a grub boot. Be sure to set your boot order in the System firmware settings. And disable hibernate and Fast Start up in windows.

Comment: Ok I'm still working on this. Not sure what "System firmware settings" is, but if it's BIOS I did that. Here's the situation: If I go into BIOS and tell it to boot from the first drive (Windows SSD), I get Windows-only boot fine. If I tell BIOS to boot from the second drive (Ubuntu HDD) it drops into the grub command line... The only way I can get the grub menu is to hold F11 during boot and selecting the second drive (Ubuntu HDD) from there. Continued in the next comment:

Comment: When I'm selecting which drive to boot in BIOS (MSI Click Bios 5), the two drives appear as: "Windows Boot Manager (P0: SanDisk SDSSDA240G)" and "ubuntu (P0: SanDisk SDSSDA240G)". Note that they have the first drive (Windows SSD) in paranthesis, event the ubuntu entry. This feels like the issue. This is what that screen looks like: https://goo.gl/images/eabL4A Any ideas what I can do? By the way, I tried Boot Repair with various options and update-grub with no help.

Comment: However, I also see "Windows Boot Manager (P0: SanDisk SDSSDA240G)" and "ubuntu (P0: SanDisk SDSSDA240G)" when holding F11 to boot, but when I select ubuntu then, it works. Weird...

Comment: I thought I'd continue on the forum here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2381307&p=13725243#post13725243